# Why does this code error on Lambda when wrapped inside exports.handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using this casperjs nodejs app:  https://github.com/narainsagar/node-casperjs-aws-lambda

I've gotten my code to work locally and when uploaded to Lambda, but I need to wrap my code inside exports.handler so I can pass data to and from the function from the API gateway.  (I already do this with other functions that are not using this app.)  When I put my code inside exports.handler it fails.  I have tested adding the event data to a test event inside lambda and I've tried hardcoding it.  Both fail when my code is inside exports.handler.  Why is exports.handler breaking this code?

Working code w/o exports.handler:

```
var ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1'
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {width: 768, height: 1024},
    userAgent: ua
});
var login = {email: 'fakeemail@gmail.com', pw: 'fakepw'}
var usrObj = {
    succ: {},
    err: []
};

//exit function
function exit() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        casper.exit();
        casper.bypass(1);
    }, 10);
}
//success & error message function
function message(dat) {
    if (dat === 'credentials') {
        console.log('Error: Login credentials are missing');
        return exit();
    }
    else if (dat) {
        console.log(dat);
        return exit();
    }

    if (usrObj['err'].length > 0) {
        console.log('Error not empty...');
        console.log(usrObj.err);
        return exit();
    }
    else if (usrObj['succ']) {
        console.log('Success not empty...');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(usrObj.succ));
        return exit();
    }

}

//trim login credentials
login.email = login.email.trim();
login.pw = login.pw.trim();

if (login.email && login.pw) {

    casper.start('https://vimeo.com/log_in');
    casper.waitForSelector('form#login_form',
        function success() {
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
            this.sendKeys('form#login_form input[name="email"]', login.email);
            this.sendKeys('form#login_form input[name="password"]', login.pw);
            this.click('form#login_form input[type=submit][value="Log in with email"]');
        },
        function fail() {
            message('Error with Vimeo [page not loading]')
        }
    );
    casper.waitForSelector('#page_header>h1>a',
        function success() {
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); 
            usrObj['succ']['uname'] = this.getHTML('span.topnav_user_name');
            usrObj['succ']['profile'] = this.getElementAttribute('li.topnav_user_profile>a', 'href');
            var test = [];
            if (!usrObj.succ.uname) {test.push('Username not retrieved')}
            if (!usrObj.succ.profile) {test.push('Profile link not retrieved')}
            if (test.length > 0) {message(test.join('<br />'));}
            //else {message();}
        }, 
        function fail() {
            message('Login not successful');
        }
    ); 
    casper.thenOpen('https://vimeo.com/staceydavidgearz', 
        function success() {
            this.echo('Stacey David Profile: ' + this.getTitle());
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); 
            var finish = function() {
                usrObj['succ']['foll'] = true;
                message();
            }
            //var foll = this.getHTML('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"] > span');
            var foll = this.getElementAttribute('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"] > svg', 'viewBox');
            if (foll === '0 0 10 10') {
                this.click('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"]');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    foll = this.getElementAttribute('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"] > svg', 'viewBox');
                    if (foll === '0 0 10 10') {
                        message('Can\'t follow SD');

                    }
                    else {finish();}
                }, 250);
            }
            else {
                finish();
            }
        },
        function fail() {
            message('Not going to Stacey David profile page.');
        }
    );

    casper.run();
}
else {message('credentials');}
```

Code failing inside exports.handler:

```
var ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1';

var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {width: 768, height: 1024},
    userAgent: ua//,
    //verbose: true,
    //logLevel: 'debug'
});

exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    var login = {};
    var usrObj = {
        succ: {},
        err: []
    };
    //exit function
    var exit = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            casper.page.close();
            casper.exit();
            casper.bypass(1);
        }, 10);
    };
    //success & error message function
    var message = function(dat) {
        if (dat === 'credentials') {
            usrObj['err'].push('Error: Login credentials are missing');
        }
        else if (dat) {
            usrObj['err'].push(dat);
        }

        if (usrObj['err'].length > 0) {
            console.log('Error not empty...');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(usrObj.err));
            context.fail(JSON.stringify(usrObj.err));
            return exit();
        }
        else if (usrObj['succ']) {
            console.log('Success not empty...');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(usrObj.succ));
            context.succeed(JSON.stringify(usrObj.succ));
            return exit();
        }
    };

    //trim login credentials
    login.email = event.email;
    login.pw = event.pw;

    if (login.email && login.pw) {

        casper.start('https://vimeo.com/log_in');
        casper.waitForSelector('form#login_form',
            function success() {
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
                this.sendKeys('form#login_form input[name="email"]', login.email);
                this.sendKeys('form#login_form input[name="password"]', login.pw);
                this.click('form#login_form input[type=submit][value="Log in with email"]');
            },
            function fail() {
                message('Error with Vimeo [page not loading]')
            }
        );
        casper.waitForSelector('#page_header>h1>a',
            function success() {
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); 
                usrObj['succ']['uname'] = this.getHTML('span.topnav_user_name');
                usrObj['succ']['profile'] = this.getElementAttribute('li.topnav_user_profile>a', 'href');
                var test = [];
                if (!usrObj.succ.uname) {test.push('Username not retrieved')}
                if (!usrObj.succ.profile) {test.push('Profile link not retrieved')}
                if (test.length > 0) {message(test.join('<br />'));}
                //else {message();}
            }, 
            function fail() {
                message('Login not successful');
            }
        ); 
        casper.thenOpen('https://vimeo.com/staceydavidgearz', 
            function success() {
                this.echo('Stacey David Profile: ' + this.getTitle());
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); 
                var finish = function() {
                    usrObj['succ']['foll'] = true;
                    message();
                }
                var foll = this.getElementAttribute('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"] > svg', 'viewBox');
                if (foll === '0 0 10 10') {
                    this.click('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"]');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        foll = this.getElementAttribute('button[data-fatal-attraction="container:profile_page|component:follow"] > svg', 'viewBox');
                        if (foll === '0 0 10 10') {
                            message('Can\'t follow SD');

                        }
                        else {finish();}
                    }, 250);
                }
                else {
                    finish();
                }
            },
            function fail() {
                message('Not going to Stacey David profile page.');
            }
        );

        casper.run();
    }
    else {message('credentials');}
};
```

Lambda response:

Body

```
[]
```

Logs:

```
Calling casperJS:  /var/task/node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs [ '/var/task/casperjs-script.js' ] { PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE: '/var/task/phantomjs' }
child process exited with code 1
```

Comment: I changed exports.handler to casper.handler and it runs until it times out.  Before I was just getting the logs above almost immediately.

Comment: What I discovered after digging into the index.js file of this app.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152784/how-to-retrieve-event-data-of-exports-handler-from-another-script

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also upload your dependencies "node_modules" with the casper component.
The error is given because in lambda execution does not find that component in require.

Comment: That app zips and uploads all dependencies.  As I said it's working when I don't wrap my code inside exports.handler, so I don't think it's a dependency problem.

Comment: It is an idea but I think casper.js tries to call an executable "installed from here http://phantomjs.org/download.html" in '/var/task/phantomjs', for this reason even going up all Dependencies in lambda execution do not find installed in the lamba container such executable and show that error

Comment: The entire log: `START RequestId: 963d81c2-ef0f-11e6-9512-b12f2c1aac99 Version: $LATEST
2017-02-09T21:34:51.289Z 963d81c2-ef0f-11e6-9512-b12f2c1aac99 Calling casperJS:  /var/task/node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs [ '/var/task/casperjs-script.js' ] { PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE: '/var/task/phantomjs' }
2017-02-09T21:34:52.513Z 963d81c2-ef0f-11e6-9512-b12f2c1aac99 child process exited with code 1
END RequestId: 963d81c2-ef0f-11e6-9512-b12f2c1aac99
REPORT RequestId: 963d81c2-ef0f-11e6-9512-b12f2c1aac99 Duration: 1247.28 ms Billed Duration: 1300 ms  Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB `

Comment: PhantomJS is uploaded as an executable by this app, so I don't think it is a dependency problem

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link: https://github.com/narainsagar/node-casperjs-aws-lambda/issues/6#issuecomment-279177650

> Hi, You can pass your data to **scraper** script via casper args support:
>
> make some changes in runCasper function in index.js file like this:
>
> ```
>  var childArgs = [
>  path.join(__dirname, scriptName),
>  ***@***.***',
>  '--password=12345'
>  ];
> ```
>
> and in your casper-script you can get the parameters data like this
> below:
>
> ```
>  var utils = require('utils');
>
>  utils.dump(casper.cli.get('email'));
>  utils.dump(casper.cli.get('password'));
>  // OR
>  // utils.dump(casper.cli.raw.get('email'));
>  // utils.dump(casper.cli.raw.get('password'));
> ```
>
> Hope this helps..

Cheers,

Narain